# Aligning equations horizontally using `enumerate` oraz `multicols`

Tags: equations, multicol

I am trying to write two equations in two columns (one equation per column). Please see my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=25mm, left=30mm, right=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} % package for custom symbols in enumerating
\usepackage{multicol} % package for displaying multiple columns in enumerate

\begin{document}

\textbf{Task 4.}
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item Find the following limits
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}[(a)]\everymath{\displaystyle}
        \item $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^34x}{x^3}$,
        \item $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{x^2} \arctan x$
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
    \item Show an example of a function with no limit.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately my examples from (i) are not aligned well. Please check the screenshot below.

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: The package tasks, instead of the package multicol